# Watchkit : Handle multiple session sendMessageData requests

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2

I have a WatchOS2 app which displays data on the watch after calling NSURLSession. Since response takes some time, if the user opens another interface controller another call goes to

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessageData:(NSData *)messageData replyHandler:(void(^)(NSData *replyMessageData))replyHandler
```

But if previous api output comes then it returns data through reply. Again the second data output should also be send. So this is giving a crash and my app hangs.

Is there a way to stop the previous reply from being sent by closing the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to cancel the previous request. It sounds like you are making the "currently visible interface controller" be the delegate of the WCSession, which would be mixing a lot of responsibilities. Instead I'd suggest adding something like a singleton class that is the permanent delegate of WCSession; and it persists and notifies, or dispatches incoming data to the right place.

Comment: Thank you.. I will add the singleton class and try it out